# Ideal threshold for detecting duplicate activity event in a web application (ex: question revisions)

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I noticed that in Stack Overflow (and sister) websites, after creating a new question if you 
edit it within some defined amount of time it won't create a new revision.

I'm developing an application which requires detecting and filtering out duplicate events within some defined time gap. But I couldn't agree on any "ideal" value for this time gap for which two same events will be considered duplicate.

So, I was wondering (in StackExchange websites), what is the time gap within which if a newly created question is edited, it doesn't create a new revision?

Comment: you will get other useful answers if you ask this on Stackoverflow

Comment: Well, I thought it belonged to meta because it was a question about StackOverflow's functionality. Will need someone with "super cow powers" to migrate it to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Five minutes.